# What building code regulations may in-office beds violate in San Francisco?

Tags: united-states, california, workplace

I read on https://fortune.com/2022/12/07/elon-musk-twitter-beds-facing-san-francisco-building-code-inspection/:

> San Francisco does not appear convinced that adding in-office beds isn’t a violation of building code regulations.

What building code regulations may in-office beds violate in San Francisco?

Comment: according to forbes, that's what the building inspectors do check at the moment.

Comment: Possibly Section 419 pertaining to live work units. https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/CABCV12019JUL21S/chapter-3-occupancy-classification-and-use

Comment: What is unequivocally illegal without planning permits is subdividing commercial space into residential units for permanent occupancy or hotel/short term occupancy. I don't think that is the accusation, even though the term "apartment" is leading in itself. What is less clear is if a business can provide private sleeping areas for employees. This is common in other contexts e.g. in hospitals.

Comment: If "beds in a building indicate residential use" how, pray tell, are furniture stores expected to even exist?  Note:  Rhetorical question more pointing out problem with the logic the city is using rather than actually looking for answer (though if the Zoning Codes of San Francisco do make an exception for this, I wouldn't mind hearing it.).

Comment: @hszmv Presumable they have to be beds that people are allowed to sleep in. https://www.facebook.com/UntitledGooseMemes/photos/a.125287848872569/742365297164818/?paipv=0&eav=Afax1PmssdN71qiVzeZy-QSi1n5PiIeAd79yZj5WauMj3M78JEO-sTRAF3YaF0JRrbY&_rdr

Answer (score 4):

[Chapter 7](https://codelibrary.amlegal.com/codes/san_francisco/f34d8cdf-0811-4e2d-8768-67a15f4b6738/sf_building/0-0-0-494) of the San Francisco building code sets forth a number of mechanical requirements on hotels, motels, dwelling units and so on (e.g. heating, security...). §709(b) in particular states that

> It shall be unlawful for any person to use or permit another person to
> use any of the following portions of a building for sleeping purposes:
>
> (1)   A hallway, water closet or bath or shower compartment, slop sink
> room, or any room containing a gas appliance used or intended to be
> used for cooking purposes or containing an improperly vented gas
> appliance;
>
> (2)   Any other room or place which does not comply with the
> provisions of this Code for a sleeping room, or in which sleeping is
> dangerous, or prejudicial to life or health by reason of an
> overcrowded condition; a lack of light, windows, ventilation or
> drainage; fire hazard, dampness or offensive, obnoxious or poisonous
> odors in the room or place.

This is sufficient grounds, given a complaint of purported violation, to mandate an inspection to determine if there has been a violation.

Answer (score 3):

### The office isn’t in a residential zone

San Francisco, like most modern cities has zoning laws and grants specific conditions on building use as well. The Twitter headquarters is in a commercial zone and no doubt has permission to be used as an office.

It isn’t in a residential zone nor approved as a residence so *people can’t live there*. Putting in beds doesn’t mean people *are* living there … but it might.

Comment: Is there a specific part of the San Francisco building code that forbids residential use in a zone where commercial use is allowed? Commercial use in a residential area is often forbidden, and not the opposite.

Comment: I don't know any US details, but in other countries residents are legally protected from excessive noise or other factors making things unpleasant. On the other hand, businesses in a non-residential area can disallow you from becoming a resident. So the business next door to Twitter might be able to say "no, we don't want to be bound by laws protecting residents. That's why we have an office in a commercial zone. " Like a business making lots of noise in the middle of the night; fine in a commercial zone.

Comment: There was an unfortunate case in Germany, where a family home had been there for 100 years and a commercial zone developed around it. For some reasons they didn't have the usual protections of residential use. Then the house burned down. The insurance was (not very) happy to rebuild it. But because that would have been a new home the family would have had the right to stop lots of commercial use. The businesses on the other hand had the choice not to let them rebuild their home, which they did. And a contract saying they couldn't complain would have been illegal and unenforceable.

Comment: FYI there are a half-dozen hotels within a block of the building, putting paid to a general "no sleeping here" rule.

Comment: @user6726 hotels are commercial, not residential. The rule is on not living there rather than not sleeping